# DataFrame.apply calls __array__ on return value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to groupby a dataframe and convert each series to a custom class. However, I find this process calls the __array__ method on the target type. It doesn't appear to do anything with the output.

I have reduced the problem to this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class A():
    def __array__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("__array__ called")
        return np.zeros(1)

def to_A(vals):
    return A()

df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9]] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = df.apply(to_A)
print(df2)
```

The output of this is:

```
__array__ called
__array__ called
A    <__main__.A object at 0x000001794D6D9510>
B    <__main__.A object at 0x000001794EB13D10>
dtype: object
```

In my case, the call to __array__ can be quite expensive.

Why does it do this / how do I prevent it from happening?

Any workarounds? Just trying to groupby and then create an instance of a class for each group.

Comment: When the return value is list-like, it's spread into the values in each row of the result. So it tries to convert it to an array, since that's one of the list-like types.

Comment: It doesn't appear to do anything with the result. Why is each row not the output of np.zeroes(1), but still my instance of A?